# Apply all child classes to parent elements

Tags: jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

I currently have the following markup:

```html
<div class="foo">
  <ul class="bar">
    <li class="a"></li>
    <li class="b"></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="foo">
  <ul class="bar">
    <li class="c"></li>
    <li class="d"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And I need to and up with the following, by getting all classes form the child li and applying them to only that specific .foo:

```html
<div class="foo a b">
  <ul class="bar">
    <li class="a"></li>
    <li class="b"></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="foo c d">
  <ul class="bar">
    <li class="c"></li>
    <li class="d"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So far I have the following, but it's only at the stage of getting the first li class and it applies it to all .foo divs as opposed to each specific one.

```js
$(".foo").addClass($('.bar li').attr('class'));
```

Any pointers in the right direction are very welcome.

Comment: Might I ask why you want to do this dynamically, instead of just changing your original CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *iterate* over the `.foo` elements and then get the class of each of their respective descendants:

```
$('.foo').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass($(this).find('.bar li').map(function() {
        return this.className;
    }).get().join(' '));
});
```

**Reference**: [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

An other, though slower method, because of the `.foo` lookup, would be:

```
$('.bar li').each(function() {
    $(this).closest('.foo').addClass(this.className);
});
```

**Reference**: [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I had just gotten into the iteration part and was fumbling around and you expressed it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that does what you need to do:

```
$('.foo').each(function(i, elem) {
    get_child_classes(this,elem);
});

//the function you need
function get_child_classes (parent,current){
    $(current).each(function(i, elem) {
        $(elem).children().each(function(j, elem1){
            $(parent).addClass($(elem1).attr('class'));
            get_child_classes (parent, elem1);
        });
    });
}
```

see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Zpx8R/
​
This code should work for all elements, no matter what type of HTML element it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('.foo').addClass(function() {
    var cls = '';
    $('li', this).each(function() {
        cls += this.className.concat(' ');
    });
    return cls;
  });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/14/)